# Is the effective HTTP status code the same as the last one given, when there are many for one request?

Tags: http

PHP snippet for a HTTP HEAD:

```
$context  = stream_context_create (
Array
(
    'http' => Array ('method' => 'HEAD')
));

$fd = fopen ("http://google.com", 'rb', false, $context);

print_r (stream_get_meta_data ($fd));
```

I am interested in the status code. Here is the result of the above

```
Array
(
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTTP/1.0 302 Found
            [1] => Cache-Control: private
            [2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [3] => Location: http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jsMQWK3GAarA8gfKnbGQAg
            [4] => Content-Length: 261
            [5] => Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 14:54:06 GMT
            [6] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
            [7] => Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 14:54:06 GMT
            [8] => Expires: -1
            [9] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
            [10] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
            [11] => P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
            [12] => Server: gws
            [13] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
            [14] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
            [15] => Set-Cookie: NID=89=Mmm0qhGNf70J0iWVbQO_whrKBG3-RNGXpkKBm9DorsWkEzMMXQfZ5qC9s5MhVwHrRXYPFmi6Q_5B0h1au7zLKDwBmgtmTPzljoQcG_jm7qqupQjR6YO38TXmnTQMNskH; expires=Thu, 27-Apr-2017 14:54:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk; HttpOnly
            [16] => Accept-Ranges: none
            [17] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
        )

    [wrapper_type] => http
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => rb
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 
    [uri] => http://google.com
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
)
```

Note the following:

```
wrapper_data[0] => HTTP/1.0 302 Found
wrapper_data[3] => Location: http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jsMQWK3GAarA8gfKnbGQAg
wrapper_data[6] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

**What is the correct procedure, in general, for determining the *effective* (what the user will see in a browser) HTTP status code?**

I am tempted to simply take the last line matching `/^HTTP\/[\d\.]+ (\d+)/`, is that going to work all the time or is it naive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of 302 is that a new Request is sent, so in this case there have really been two Requests and two Responses. The first status code is not relevant to the user unless the second Request failed (there was no Response).

It would be safe to treat the status code of the last received response as the relevant one in virtually all cases (except if debugging or tracing is what you're after). Any status codes before it were only needed to get to that last status code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation on this, but it would appear that the `wrapper_data` array is filled in order.

So first you get the redirect response (302), followed by the actual response (200). This means you can start reading at the last header starting with `HTTP/`.

You definitely don't get all these headers in response for one request, but rather, the wrapper executes the redirected request transparently and appends the headers for the second response to those of the first.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you would ever get more than 1 valid response to a single request is if all but the last response are in the range 100-199, which is the set of interim responses.  For example a 100 Continue response to a POST followed by the actual result response of the POST itself.